# removing redudant kernal libraries after kernal reinstallation

Tags: ubuntu, vps, openvz, linux-kernel

I'm learning to administer a VPS which has an openVZ kernel (= go easy...). I thought I'd attempt to load a missing kernal module by reinstalling my kernel with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Not only did that fail to get the module I needed, my disk usage doubled. My VPS host admin loaded the module in the host kernel which solved that issue. But now I have 8+GB of redundant OS libraries for Ubuntu 18.04. How can i remove these redundant libraries? `apt auto-remove` didn't help.

Besides starting from scratch, would appreciate suggestions how one can reclaim the 8+GB of SSD space I carelessly lost!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just uninstall the package, but before you do, please read the rest of the answer.

If the command you provided in your question ran without an error message, you didn't reinstall your actual kernel but installed another one (that isn't used now).
If you just run `apt-get install` on an already installed package you get the following output:

```
linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-137.163)
```

and apt-get does nothing. Since it installed something on your server, it must be a package that wasn't installed before.

So, to make absolutely sure you are not uninstalling your current kernel, run the following:

```
$ dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-`uname -r`
linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic
```

This let's dpkg search for the package that contains the currently running kernel (based on the filename in `/boot`).

In my case the package name is `linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic`, for your virtual server it most probably will be different.

If this package name differs from the package you installed earlier, you can safely uninstall the unwanted package.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

running `sudo apt-get autoremove` afterwards should take care of all dependencies.

Comment: `$ dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-\`uname -r\``<br/>
`dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0` However, `/boot` contains around 50 other vmlinuz-4.15.0 variants ending in both different numeric and text suffixes, e.g., -1004-oem, -1006-gcp, -1007-aws, -1008-kvm, -1009-azure, -20-lowlatency besides of course generic. I'm assuming these are redundant. Is there a way to remove most or all of them together using apt or dpkg without removing what's needed, which i assume would be vmlinuz-4.15.0-38-generic?